# get a list of file from the classpath

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to test an utility method.

I need to create a list of files from the ressource directory of my project.

I can create one file at a time, but i need to iterate over all files in my directory.

My test method looks like:

```
 @Test
    public void testFileRessourceLoader(){
        ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        File file = new File(loader.getResource("exacts/graph_968_26_8.lst").getFile());
        System.out.println(file.getName());
    }
```

The structure of the files i want to read. I need a way to not type the name of every file in my program. The solution should be easy and not depending on some libraries.

[image]

Comment: Add a file that contains the list of all the other files. Read this list and loop over it. You asked simple and without a library, so that's pretty much it. Other solutions are complicated or with a library, and use hacks that aren't guaranteed to live on with the language.

Comment: Are you looking for a listing of the `exacts` dir?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Path exacts = Paths.get(getClass().getResource("/exacts").toURI());
Stream<Path> files = Files.list(exacts);
files.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.getName()));
```

Comment: getFileName() in place of getName, because it didn't work. thank you.

Comment: @zakzak I didn’t compile it, so not surprised. Glad to help.